# XSD attributes specifying

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to create .xsd schema, and specify attribute. How I can do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConfigData>
   <GlobalSettings>    
      <Logging param="Off"/> <-- param can be only in 'On' or 'Off' statement -->
   </GlobalSettings>
</ConfigData>
```

I created something like this, but it doesn`t work

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ConfigData">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="GlobalSettings">
          <xs:complexType>            
            <xs:simpleType name="statement">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="On"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Off"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element name="Logging">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="param" type="statement" use="required"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: if u get this accept it as answer pls

Comment: Did the answers to your question help you?

Answer (score 1):

```
<price currency="euros">20000.00</price>
```

restrict the currency attribute to one the following:

```
euros
pounds
dollars


<xs:simpleType name="curr">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="pounds" />
    <xs:enumeration value="euros" />
    <xs:enumeration value="dollars" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>



<xs:element name="price">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
              <xs:attribute name="currency" type="curr"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Attributes are optional by their nature so `<price>1000</price>` is also valid. To prevent this you can add `use="required"` attribute to the `<xs:attribute` declaration.

Comment: where do I need to paste "simpleType" container? I edited question to show what i did, but it isn`t correct

Answer (score 0):

If you define a new simpleType and you want to refer to it from another location, you need to define it at the top level, directly within an `<xs:schema>` element.

Your schema has other problems beyond the simpleType: you cannot define another `<xs:element>` directly under `<xs:complexType>`, rather you first need to say whether you want an `<xs:sequence>`, `<xs:choice>` or `<xs:all>`. In your case, the result is the same since you only have one `<GlobalSettings>` element under `<ConfigData>`, and one `<Logging>` element under GlobalSettings. So let's pick `<xs:sequence>`.

Your **schema** then becomes:

```
<xs:simpleType name="onOffType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="On" />
        <xs:enumeration value="Off" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="ConfigData">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="GlobalSettings">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Logging">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:attribute name="param" type="onOffType" use="required" />
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This validates your input file and raises a validation error if the value of the `param` attribute on your `<Logging>` element is anything other than *On* or *Off*.